# DITA XSLT - writing meta tags as keywords

Tags: xslt, dita

I am using XSLT from the DITA-OT (h2d.xsl) to convert HTML meta keyword tags to their DITA equivalent, for example in HTML:

`<meta name="MS-HAID" content="cake" />
    <meta name="MS-HAID" content="pie" />
    <meta name="MS-HAID" content="tart" />
    <meta name="search-keywords" content="creme brulee" />`

I would like it to appear as DITA keywords, i.e.

```
<keywords>
<keyword>cake</keyword>
<keyword>pie</keyword>
<keyword>tart</keyword>
<keyword>creme brulee</keyword>
</keywords>
```

I can write out each keyword, but each instance also contains the keywords element as well. I need help understanding what to select so keywords is written only once. Here is my current XSLT:

```
<xsl:template name="keyword-match" match="meta" mode="outofline"> 
<keywords>
  <keyword><xsl:value-of select="@content" /></keyword>
  </keywords>
  </xsl:template>
```

Thanks very much. I've tried a billion different ways and I just can't get my head around it.

-----Update-----

I came up with the following solution based on @tobias-klevenz example. Since there are other meta tags before the keyword tags, I had to find those first. This locates the first meta tag, and then writes the keyword for each following sibling that correctly matches the name parameter.

```
<xsl:template match="/html/head[1]/meta[1]" mode="outofline">
<keywords>
  <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::node()[@name='MS-HAID' or @name='search-keywords' or @name='keywords']">
    <keyword><xsl:apply-templates select="@content" /></keyword>
  </xsl:for-each>
        </keywords>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the `apply-templates` that selects meta with `<keywords>`:

```
<xsl:template match="html">
    <keywords>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="meta" mode="outofline"/>
    </keywords>

...
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="keyword-match" match="meta" mode="outofline"> 
    <keyword><xsl:value-of select="@content" /></keyword>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Alternative:**

```
<!-- match first meta -->
<xsl:template name="keyword-match" match="meta[1]" mode="outofline">
    <keywords> 
        <keyword><xsl:value-of select="@content" /></keyword>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::meta"/>
    </keywords>
</xsl:template>
<!-- match following meta -->
<xsl:template name="keyword-match" match="meta[position() &gt; 1]" mode="outofline"> 
    <keyword><xsl:value-of select="@content" /></keyword>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, Tobias. It's not writing out the keywords element, but I think there may be a conflict within the larger h2d.xsl. At least this gets me a bit closer.

Comment: @hamonwry I updated my answer with an Alternative were you don't have to update the parent template

Comment: I came up with an alternate solution based on your answer @tobias-klevenz (see above). Thanks again.